# Upgraded to Samba 4.11 and now windows 10 doesn't see the server

Tags: windows-10, centos, network-shares, samba

I had samba working as a standalone server on a Centos 8 server and a windows 10 client.
Then I upgraded to samba 4.11 and everything broke down.

Here's the smb.conf file

```
[global]
        path = /srv/smb
        writeable = yes
        security = user
        netbios name = konishiki
        wins support = yes
        local master = yes
        preferred master = yes
        client min protocol = SMB2
        client max protocol = SMB3
        sync always = yes
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        log level = 2
        unix password sync = no
        vfs objects = acl_xattr
        map acl inherit = yes
        wins support = yes
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        admin users = hank, hankwin hcohe
[homes]
        inherit acls = Yes
        browseable = no
        writable = yes
        path = /home
        comment = Home Directories
[hankwin]
        path = /srv/smb/hankwin/
        read only = no
[hank]
        path = /srv/smb/hank
        read only = no
        create mask = 777
```

On the server side, [konishiki was the biggest sumo wrestler in history so I use his name for my big file server] smbclient gives me the following report:

```
[root@konishiki samba]# smbclient -L localhost -U%

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        hankwin         Disk
        hank            Disk
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.11.2)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Seems to me that what I want is for SMB1 to be disabled.  That's the big improvement in samba 4.0 but why is no workgroup available?

On the client side (akaoninoko is my client) net view gives this:

```
C:\Users\hcohe>net view
Server Name            Remark
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\AKAONINOKO
The command completed successfully.
```

Obviously, akaoninoko doesn't see the shares from konishiki.
Name resolution is working and I can ping between all hosts without any problems.
I have run netshark on both interfaces and confirmed that browsing messages are being passed around and konishiki has won the election to be local master but the windows 10 client doesn't seem to have gotten the message. (pcap available on request).

Other things I have tried:
I uninstalled SMB1 support on the client but that led to a worse condition where the net view command generated a system error.
[sorry I would like to show the error message but I would need to uninstall SMB1 support again and reboot which takes a lot of time.]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Hank

Answer (score 2):

I think you want two opposite things here.

> Seems to me that what I want is for SMB1 to be disabled. That's the big improvement in samba 4.0 but why is no workgroup available?

As your Samba configuration has `client min protocol = SMB2`, it also prevents smbclient from using SMBv1 to query the server's workgroup name – an operation which has no SMBv2/3 equivalent.

(`client min protocol` is not about *connecting* clients – it's about Samba's *own* [lib]smbclient. The option for changing which protocol the Samba server speaks to other clients is `server min protocol`.)

In general, workgroups were a concept only relevant to NetBIOS, which was intermingled with SMBv1 and is usually disabled together with it. Workgroups do not interact with SMB file sharing directly – they existed to group computers for NetBIOS' "browsing", mainly for technical reasons to reduce load on the elected browsers.

> I uninstalled SMB1 support on the client but that led to a worse condition where the net view command generated a system error.

Uninstalling SMBv1 on Windows also uninstalls NetBIOS support. Note that unlike your Samba configuration (which only tells the 'smbd' daemon to refuse SMBv1 negotiation and does not affect the 'nmbd' NetBIOS daemon), removing SMBv1 on Windows *actually removes* the kernel driver which implements the protocol.

The browsing messages, in particular, are exchanged via SMBv1 "mailslots" – so even though 'nmbd' may still be running on the Samba side, there's nothing on Windows to pay attention to it anymore.

---

The replacement "browsing" protocol preferred by Windows is WS-Discovery, which is handled by a different system service ('Function Discovery' something-or-other). Explorer will automatically use both services and show both NetBIOS and WSD results in the 'Network' tab, but *net view* hasn't been updated to talk to the new service.

WS-Discovery is not part of Samba, but there are at least two Linux implementations ([wsdd](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd) and [wsdd2](https://github.com/Andy2244/wsdd2)). WSD still has a 'workgroup' parameter but doesn't use it like NetBIOS did.

(Linux and macOS would probably prefer DNS-SD via mDNS, but although Windows already supports mDNS for hostname resolution and printer discovery, it doesn't yet support it for SMB service discovery.)